# Query to insert database PDO with foreach

Tags: php, database, pdo

How i can insert this query in database PDO?

```
    public function insertPessoa($estado){

                $this->$estado = $estado;

                echo "<pre>";
                $linkDeputados =

 file_get_contents('https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados?siglaUf='.$estado.'&ordem=ASC&itens=100&ordenarPor=nome&pagina=1');
            $json = json_decode($linkDeputados);
            $deputados = (object) $json;
            $connectar = new PDO("pgsql:host=localhost; dbname=postgres", "postgres", "123456");


            foreach ($deputados->dados as $objeto => $o)
            {
                $sql = " INSERT INTO  deputados 
                                            (   id,
                                                'nome', 
                                                'estado',
                                                'web_partido', 
                                                'sigla_partido',
                                                'url_foto'
                                            ) 

                        VALUES
                                            (   
                                                 {$o->id},
                                                '{$o->nome}', 
                                                '{$o->siglaUf}', 
                                                '{$o->uriPartido}', 
                                               '{$o->siglaPartido}',
                                                '{$o->urlFoto}'

                                            )";

            }

            $query = $connectar->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindValue(':id', $o->id);
            $query->bindValue(':nome', $o->nome);
            $query->bindValue(':estado', $o->siglaUf);
            $query->bindValue(':web_partido', $o->uriPartido);
            $query->bindValue(':sigla_partido', $o->siglaPartido);
            $query->bindValue(':url_foto', $o->urlFoto);

            $query->execute();

            if($query){
                echo 'Registro Inseridos com Sucesso!<br>';
            }

        }
```

This give me a error:

> Warning:  PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid
>   parameter number: :id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisaDeputados\pessoa.class.php on line 79

Comment: This function is part of a class, are you creating a new pdo connection within every function, isso que você está fazendo?

Comment: Yes, this function is part of my class and i use de PDO connection for the ohter functions too...it's wrong?

Comment: I think the `foreach` loop should close after `$query->execute();` not before `$query = $connectar->prepare($sql);`

Comment: You should create a new class for the db connection and then just inject the connection into your class, that way you're not creating a new connection over and over. Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysqli doesn't find the `:id` string in your sql query because you are injecting the object not using prepared statements

You sql statement should be:

```
$sql = " INSERT INTO  deputados 
                                        (   id,
                                            'nome', 
                                            'estado',
                                            'web_partido', 
                                            'sigla_partido',
                                            'url_foto'
                                        ) 

                    VALUES
                                        (   
                                             :id,
                                            :nome, 
                                            :estado, 
                                            :uri_partido, 
                                            :sigla_partido,
                                            :url_foto

                                        )";
```

and you need to bind the param not the values

Comment: Hi buddy! Ok, but i see the documentation, my question is... i using de foreach to interate object proprierts, this case in {$o->uriPartido} acess the value of my object...see this: object(stdClass)#39 (8) { ["id"]=> int(160569) ["uri"]=> string(58) "dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/160569"; ["nome"]=> string(16) "WALDENOR PEREIRA" ["siglaPartido"]=> string(2) "PT" ["siglaUf"]=> string(2) "BA" ["idLegislatura"]=> int(55) ["urlFoto"]=> string(60) "camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/160569.jpg"; } 

How i can acess the values of this object??

Comment: using the arrow notation `$obj->property`

Comment: I don't need to use $obj->property in VALUES of the query to Set the value inside foreach?

Comment: your code should work right now, what's the problem?

Comment: I change the code and continue to get error message:

Comment: Warning:  PDOStatement::bindValue(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: :nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\pesquisaDeputados\pessoa.class.php on line 79

Comment: Yeah Bro! This solve the error, but do not populate my table on database...

I do a var_dump in my query->BinValue and return:

object(PDOStatement)#23 (1) {
  ["queryString"]=>
     (   
        :id,
        :nome, 
        :estado,
        :web_partido
     )
 VALUES
 (   
        :id,
        :nome, 
        :estado,
        :web_partido, 
        :sigla_partido,
        :url_foto
                                            
)";

This not returning the value of object propriert anymore...://

Comment: make sure your id is unique, prepared statements don't output the content of the variables ,mysqli send the query first and then the values

Comment: Yes, i check the dabatase columns and not have change

Comment: you have a insert statement not a update, you should have another row of data, not changed data

Comment: Yes i know, i delete all rows of my table for see if have any problem with primary keys, but this is not the problem...problably the query is returning a proprierts with no values... i trying to solve sothis problem

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) you will see that you should be using `:id,:nome,:estado` in the values list of the insert statement instead of inserting values directly.

Comment: Hi buddy! Ok, but i see the documentation, my question is... i using de foreach to interate object proprierts, this case in {$o->uriPartido} acess the value of my object...see this:

object(stdClass)#39 (8) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(160569)
  ["uri"]=>
  string(58) "https://dadosabertos.camara.leg.br/api/v2/deputados/160569"
  ["nome"]=>
  string(16) "WALDENOR PEREIRA"
  ["siglaPartido"]=>
  string(2) "PT"
  ["siglaUf"]=>
  string(2) "BA"
  ["idLegislatura"]=>
  int(55)
  ["urlFoto"]=>
  string(60) "http://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/160569.jpg"
}